# I want to return amount

Tags: angular

I want to return amount to the given function.

I have make a function

```
    getWalletTotalAmont()
  {
    let amount= 0 ;

    this.http.post<any>(`${this.generalService.apiBaseUrl}api/wallet/getWalletTotal`,{user_id:2}).pipe(map(data => 
      {
        return  JSON.stringify(data);
      }),

    ).subscribe((data) =>
    {  

      let data_obj = JSON.parse(data);
      amount= data_obj.total_wallet_amount; 
      console.log(amount);   // it is printing 2500
    },

    );
    return amount;   // it is returning 0

  }
```

Comment: How can i return the amount to the function?

Comment: Also you should provide an actual generic type, and why do you stringify and then parse the response again?!

Comment: @jonrsharpe can you provide, the simplify code of above function, As I am new to angular

Comment: @Shubh you return an *observable* of the result.

Comment: Then I'd suggest running through https://angular.io/tutorial

Comment: @Shubh I'd suggest you also run through it. https://angular.io/guide/http is useful for this specific topic too.

Answer (score 3):

When using observables you don't return the actual value, but an observable. The observable is a stream where you subscribe to listen for events. The event is actually the http response. Normally handling http request in angular is done like this:

```
getWalletTotalAmont(): Observable<any>{
  return this.http.post<any>(`${this.generalService.apiBaseUrl}api/wallet/getWalletTotal`,{user_id:2})
}
```

No need to call json.parse angular does that automatically.

And you can use this function in different ways in your component:

```
@Component(...)
export class MyComponent  {
   amount;

   constructor(private walletService: WalletService) {}

   loadWalletAmount() {
    this.walletService.getWalletAmount().subscribe(amount=> {this.amount = amount});
   }
  }
```

You trigger a function in your component which calls the service and write the result to a local variable in this case `amount`. Afterwards this variable can be used in your component to display the result.

An alternative is to use angulars `async pipe`:

```
  @Component(...)
    export class MyComponent implements OnInit  {
       amount$: Observable<any>;

       constructor(private walletService: WalletService) {}

       ngOnInit() {
        this.amount$ = this.walletService.getWalletAmount();
       }
      }
```

And in your template:

```
<div *ngIf="amount$ | async as amount>
  My amount is {{amount}}
</div>
```

EDIT:

If you want to show the amount on multiple views you have to provide a public variable of the service.

For example:

```
     @Injectable()
        export class WalletService {

          // I don't know what amount is, it would be better to provide a non null value here      
          amount: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
          get amount$(): Observable<any> {
            return this.amount.asObservable();
          }

          constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
            this.getWallet();
          }

          getWallet() {
            this.http.post<any>(`${this.generalService.apiBaseUrl}api/wallet/getWalletTotal`,{user_id:2})
            .subscribe(amount => this.amount=amount)
          }
        }
```

Then you can access the amount$ from anywhere:

```
 @Component(...)
    export class MyComponent implements OnInit  {
       amount: any;

       constructor(private walletService: WalletService) {}

       ngOnInit() {
        this.walletService.amount$.subscribe(amount => this.amount = amount);
       }
      }
```

BehaviorSubject saves the last emitted value and every new subscriber gets immediately this value.

Comment: But I want to return amount in the given function,as I want do display wallet amount lots of places.

Comment: See my edit. You have to expose a shared observable `get amount$(): Observable<any> {
            return this.amount.asObservable();
          }` in the service which then any component can access.

Comment: @ J.S. Can you help a bit more?

Comment: @ J.s  Wallet amount is not working on fine page refresh, however it is working on again click...

Comment: It depends on when valletService.getWallet() gets called. This function updates the value in BehaviorSubject. In my example it is called in the constructor of WalletService, but you can call it from everywhere. The best thing would be if you call it inside of `ngOnInit` of your component.